# Getting "type or namespace name could not be found" when I try to import mudblazor?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I have a blazor application and I installed mudblazor through nuget package manager but I can't import it to imports file because i am getting CS0246 error (type or namespace name could not be found).

[MudBlazor Install For project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVbzB.png)

[CS0246 Error type or namespace name could not be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP1XT.png)

Comment: Unable to duplicate the problem.  Followed the [MudBlazor instructions](https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#prerequisites) to create a project from a template, opened the project in VSCode, and typed dotnet run.  All OK.  Suggest building their template app and comparing it to your project to see what is different.

Answer (score 1):

It's Mud**B**lazor (capital B), not Mud**b**lazor